# Finding aggregated counts by past time frame

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables.

First is a table of a patient visiting a hospital. Each visit has a unique id given by VisitId. Each Patient is uniquely identified by ID. Here is what the table a sample record from the table looks like.

```
 ID VisitID VisitTime
1   A   7/5/12 6:21
2   B   7/5/12 6:21
1   C   10/28/13 12:30
2   D   1/8/11 12:07
3   E   7/5/12 6:21
```

Here the ID is a patientid. VisitID is the hospital visit id and visit time is the time of visit. A patient can be part of multiple visits so same ID would be present for different VisitID too. But the VisitID is unique across the table and has one record per visitID.

Now there is another table which keeps tab of a patient medication dispensation in the hospital.

```
  MedicationID  VisitID MedicationTIme
1   A   7/4/12 12:30
2   A   7/5/12 6:21
2   A   10/8/11 12:07
3   A   10/28/10 12:30
1   B   7/5/12 6:21
3   B   10/28/13 12:30
3   C   5/5/13 6:21
2   C   7/5/12 6:21
1   C   1/8/11 12:07
```

Here each medication is identified by a medicationid. For each visit what all medication has been dispensed to a patient we have each record for the same. So each VisitID in this table might be repeated as there would be different medication given to a patient in the same visit. Time here is the medication time.

Now what I want is that in the first table where I have unique combination of patient (ID) and VistiID, the count of medications the patient was given 6 months before the current visit, 12 months before the current visit and so on. Basically since each record in the first table corresponds to a visit by a patient in the hospital I would want all these variables to be added to the first table corresponding each record telling me that for this current visit this patient had x no. of medication in the past 6 months/12 month and so visits to hospital. So in the end I would have the same no. of rows as the first table with some few additional columns added.

Please note that the first table can have multiple ID being repeated as one patient can be part of multiple visits to hospitals. And we want for a particular combination of ID+VisitID, whats the count of medication that patient had before that visit(given by visitID and Visittime).

Output:

***Please note that for example visitID 'A', we see the patientID is 1. And this patient in the past also visited with visitID 'C'. So the total records in medication table corresponding to both VisitID 'A' and 'C' would be counted where the Medication time is less than the Visittime for the combination patient ID=1 and VisitID='A'. Same for other records***

```
ID  VisitID VisitTime   Totalmedication_6mnth   Totalmedication6-12mnth Totalmedication_all
1   A   7/5/12 6:21 1   2   4
2   B   7/5/12 6:21 0   0   0
1   C   10/28/13 12:30  1   0   7
2   D   1/8/11 12:07    0   0   0
3   E   7/5/12 6:21 0   0   0
```

I have done something, but looks like there is some error with respect to where clause.

Can this be done in normal sql without using windows functions of postgres?. Or can someone suggest both the solutions?. Window function and normal sql way?

Thanks

Comment: I would appreciate if both normal sql and postgres window function can be highlighted.I can learn this way.I have been using normal sql so if someone highlights the postgres also would be useful to know how it is done using window functions.  But if not, simple solution is fine too

Comment: Window functions *are* "normal SQL", so I don't understand that. Does this mean you are not using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: I am using postgres. But I don't think window functions are present in sql_server or T-Sql?. I saw them in postgres sql

Comment: They are available in SQL-Server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms189461%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Window functions have been part of the SQL *standard* for over 10 years now and all modern DBMS (including SQL Server) support them (although only recent SQL Server versions after 2012 support the full set of window functions as Postgres does)

Comment: fine my bad then. All I wanted is a solution without using window function and a solution which uses window function. :)

Comment: have updated the question with expected output

Comment: Why are there different dates for the same visit in the medication table?

Comment: Thats a good catch. It won't be. The date would only differ in time I would say. But I made those so that we could have an example of what the output should look like.